# No headers in HttpServletRequest after adding Async annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Spring-MVC controller which uses `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` in method:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/some/path")
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) {
       // some validation and preprocessing logic here, using request headers and URI
       library.process(req, rsp);
    }
}
```

`req` and `rsp` are used by another library in this method. Also, this method performs some preprocessing logic and validation using request URI and headers.

Now we want to make this method async by adding `@Async` annotation, since the library also provides method to perform asynchronous processing of the request and can return `CompletableFuture<Void>`:

```java
@EnableAsync
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/some/path")
    @Async
    public CompletionStage<Void> handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) {
      // validation and preprocessing
      return this.library.process(req, rsp);
    }
}
```

But the problem is after making this controller async, `HttpServletRequest` returns empty headers for `req.getHeaderNames()` (without async it returns correct headers for same http request). What could be a problem, and how to correctly get request headers from async request?

Comment: Adding `@Async` to a controller method doesn't make sense. The problem is the `@Async` as the request isn't available anymore in the new thread.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, but what annotation should I use then for asynchronous processing `HttpServletRequest` in another thread?

Comment: There is async support build into the servlet-api spec already use that instead.

Comment: I had a similar problem, what helped me is: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/enableasync-async-controller/